# Scrapy recursive callback

Tags: python, callback, scrapy

I'm working on a scrapy project that sends a request to some website, initiates report generation that takes around a minute to be COMPLETED. then download the generated file and parse it. ( I know that scrapy is the not the best option for this purpose but i have to use it)

Now, I have a function that checks the status of the report generation, that is supposed to be sent multiple times until the report is generated.

I read few articles on same-function callback but all mentioned only callback=None which automatically returns to the main parse function

Here is my code: I want the crawler to come back to the same function if status is not COMPLETED

```
    def parse_report_status(self, response):
        try:
            status = json.loads(response.text)
        except Exception as err:
            self.logger.error(err)
            return
        report_config = response.meta['report_config']
        trials = response.meta['trials']
        report_status = status['status']
        if report_status == 'COMPLETED':
            yield Request(
                url=DOWNLOAD_REPORT_URL.format(self.user_data['siteListEID'], report_config['id']),
                method='POST',
                callback=self.parse_data,
                meta={'report_status': report_status}
            )
        elif report_status in ["COMPLETED_WITH_ERRORS", "ERROR", "NOTFOUND"]:
            self.logger.error(f'Could not download report {report_config["id"]}')
            return
        else:
            if trials > 0:
                sleep_time = int(self.wait_time - ((self.max_trials - trials) * (self.wait_time / self.max_trials)))
                self.logger.info(f'Going to sleep for another {sleep_time} seconds')
                time.sleep(sleep_time)
                yield Request(
                    url=REPORT_STATUS_URL.format(self.user_data['siteListEID'], report_config['id']),
                    method='GET',
                    callback=self.parse_report_status,
                    meta={'report_config': report_config, 'trials': trials - 1}
                )
            else:
                self.logger.error(
                    f'Report {report_config["id"]} could not be downloaded after {self.max_trials} trial(s)')
                return
```

The issue is that the program terminates on the first call meaning it doesn't go back to the same function after first trial.

Is there any missing config that i need to add to the spider to enable same-function callback?  Is it even possible ?

wanna mention that i am using:
Scrapy 1.8.0 & python 3.6.11

Comment: Can You please add log output of scrapy application?
Especially interested in lines after `Dumping Scrapy stats:...`

Comment: @Georgiy: 
I might have found the problem .. 
DEBUG:scrapy.dupefilters:Filtered duplicate request: <GET url> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your request was filtered by scrapy duplication filter (aimed to filter requests to previously crawled/scraped pages).
add `dont_filter=True` to your report status request:

```
....
yield Request(
    url=REPORT_STATUS_URL.format(self.user_data['siteListEID'], report_config['id']),
    dont_filter=True,  # <- add this
    method='GET',
    callback=self.parse_report_status,
    meta={'report_config': report_config, 'trials': trials - 1}
)
```